# Стилизация выбранного TreeViewItem в TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf

Элементы дерева (`TreeView`):

```
   -Элемент1
      -Элемент2
      -Элемент3
        -Элемент4
        -Элемент5
   -Элемент6
```

Вот сам стиль:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <SolidColorBrush Color="Orange" x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}"/>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
         <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
         <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True" >
               <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
               <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
            </Trigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>

<TreeView HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,12" Name="treeView1" Width="189"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path='Items'}" ItemTemplate="{Binding Source={StaticResource     ResourceKey='myTaskTemplate'}}">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="TreeView\ItemTemplate\Style.xaml"/>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

Вопрос:<br>
Почему когда выделен `TreeViewItem -> "Элемент1"`, то вместе с ним жирным шрифтом и цветом `Blue` выделяются - `{"Элемент2", "Элемент3, "Элемент4", "Элемент5}` тоже?В общем, все дочерние `TreeViewItem`.

Как можно сделать, чтобы выделялся по стилю только выделенный `TreeViewItem`?
Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это происходит оттого, что свойства шрифта (в вашем случае `FontWeight`) наследуются дочерними элементами. Чтобы этого не происходило, нужно менять шрифт только элемента, отображающего сам узел, а не его подчиненные. Это можно сделать либо триггерами соответствующего узлу `DataTemplate`, либо триггерами `ControlTemplate` для `TreeViewItem`. Во втором случае жирный шрифт нужно устанавливать только для `Header` части `Expander`-а, который используется для показа узла дерева.

Comment: ммм а могли бы вы исправить мой стиль отображения, я на WPF перешёл недавно, исходя из вашего исправления пойду дальше? ))

Answer (score 0):

Всё разобрался: просто нужно было добавить Trigger на IsSelected = False )))

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <SolidColorBrush Color="Orange" x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}"/>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
         <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
         <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True" >
               <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
               <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False" >
               <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
            </Trigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```